# Xrdp connection from Win11 to RPI4

Tags: xrdp

In past I was using VNC and it worked well. Now, I want to abandon RealVNC and switch to xrdp. I have spent several hours trying to get the xrdp to work. I have went through several suggestions found with Google.  Many of those are obviously wrong and too exotic to work. I am new RPI user and have concern that some of these trials have permanently messed my system.

I would like to see less than 10 sudo commands to be applied to a new SD card to make the xrdp connection.  Where I can find the solution?

Comment: you are using a linux computer ... your question belongs at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: There is the potential for confusion between commands to install Raspberry Pi software on a new SD card and commands to run when that SD card has booted on a Raspberry Pi.  In addition, to use the RPi xrdp server, another system must have a RDP client installed.  ps:  Don''t forget about firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

First link when searching for `"raspberry pi xrdp"` is [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-raspberry-pi/)

Relevant instructions

```
sudo apt install xrdp 
sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
```

tested and working on pi3b+ running Bullseye (aarch64)

OK, for 64bit on Raspberry Pi 4 there is one more step

as seen [here](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/2060#issuecomment-979958020)

> Edit /etc/X11/xrdp/xorg.conf and set
>
> `Option "DRMDevice" ""`
>
> This disables glamor for xrdp session only.

Comment: I did try that sequence. When I did use my own password for user "pi", the end result was an empty blue screen.  When I did change the password back to "raspberry", I still got the blue screen, but this time with a dialog giving me an error message.

There could be a difference between RPI3B+ and RPI4B.

Comment: Thanks for a rapid reply.  I have been doing the testing with two different RPI4 boards with same results.  Some of the hints in internet are recommending to add a new user account just for the xrdp.  That should resolve the issue of forced use of the default password.

Comment: At the end, I do guess that I will realize what kind of newbie errors I have made. I have done several fresh installs with 32 bit and 64 bit PI OS,  The results are still the same. At the same time, I can observe that there are large number of other users who are wrestling with this same problem.  Just for checking, what are the exact user id and password you have given in the Raspberry PI imager.

Comment: I did a fresh install with pi/raspberry and used the two sudo commands you did show.  The end result was the same empty blue screen. If it seems to you that I am the only one struggling, please don't reply.

Comment: Apologies @Ollie - I thought it was working on pi 4 64bit, but I was mistaken - didn't try logging in on the pi 4 to be honest - there is a similar post on raspberry pi forums in February that has gone UNANSWERED .... seems the Pi Foundation don't give a crap about users any more

Comment: @Ollie - updated answer despite your rude attitude